# Would you like to delete these indexes? Selecting no will continue the rest of the deployment

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase always requests to delete firestore indexes when deploying.

```
The following indexes are defined in your project but are not present in your firestore indexes file:
    (users) -- (role,ASCENDING) (name,ASCENDING)
? Would you like to delete these indexes? Selecting no will continue the rest of the deployment.
```

How can I include the indexes in my local project directory? or if not, make it always remember to not delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `firebase firestore:indexes` command to print existing indexes in your project and update the file. You can then update the indexes with:

```
firebase deploy --only firestore:indexes
```

Comment: It might be best to include `firestore.indexes.json` file in your Github repository if any so its shared with others as well ^^